# Hide element with jQuery on button press

Tags: jquery

I have buttons associated with a certain choice and I wanna display a form related to the choice and remove the buttons when one of them is clicked. I hide all the forms in the beginning so the user must click the button first. This is the code:

```
$(document).load(function () {
    $("#radial, #rect").hide();
});
$("#rectS").click(function () {
    $("#rect").show(slow);
    $(".confirm").remove();
});
$("#radialS").click(function () {
    $("#radial").show(slow);
    $(".confirm").remove();
});
```

But it doesn't do anything and no one can tell me why. The hiding at the start doesn't work either, by the way. jQuery is really frustrating...

Codepen: http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/HJEzx

Comment: Please also show the HTML or provide a small http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: K. I have a full codepen. Its an exerise that is mostly for PHP, but I got stuck with jQuery and cant even move into PHP part:
http://codepen.io/megakoresh/pen/HJEzx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `slow` to `'slow'` . And wrap your code within [**`$(document).ready(function(){  });`**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to bind event after dom elements are loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radial, #rect").hide();
    $("#rectS").click(function () {
        $("#rect").show('slow');
        //--------------^----^--
        $(".confirm").remove();
    });
    $("#radialS").click(function () {
        $("#radial").show('slow');
        //----------------^----^--
        $(".confirm").remove();
    });
});
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/unlrc)

**[Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/show/](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**

Comment: Yeah I changed to "slow", still nothing. And I started with wrapping it inside the (document).ready with no result whatsoever.

Comment: Oook, so why doesn't it work in my browser? I linked the jQuery library with src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" is that wrong?

Comment: Yeah i checked it. It works in codepen, but not when I launch it localy in Chrome.

Comment: K I got it. Stupid really... I had to make a separate tag and link the library from there and then open another script tag and put the code in there and it worked. But not when I put the src into the initial script tag. WTF... Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

Put all your code in DOM Ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#radial, #rect").hide();
    $("#rectS").click(function () {
        $("#rect").show('slow');
              //        ^    ^ wrap show in quotes
        $(".confirm").remove();
    });
    $("#radialS").click(function () {
        $("#radial").show('slow');
        $(".confirm").remove();
    });
});
```